# What is the meaning of 'like' in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, formality

[image]

I think that 'like' in this sentence means 'about'.
Then, what is the difference between 'like' and 'about'?

Comment: "like" seems to take over more and more meanings. But I think this use of like for about + number is rare, if not wrong, and I would not imitate it. But The Free Dictionary has registered this usage in like 2, adverb, no. 3: like meaning nearly, approximately. Seems to be usage in AmE.

Comment: And this use of "like" seems to be a relatively new usage. Oald doesn't have this usage, neither in BrE nor in AmE.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_1

Answer (score 2):

It might mean "about", or it might mean other things. It is a common filler word in colloquial speech (especially young people), and is usually rather vague in meaning.

Many older people disapprove of its use.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it can mean *about*, and in this sentence we can say it does. However, it's not grammatically correct, and should be avoided unless you want to sound like a teenager.

I could go on and on, but here:
[I googled it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%3F%20usage%20of%20the%20word%20like%20in%20teenage%20speech&gws_rd=ssl#q=usage%20of%20the%20word%20like%20in%20teenage%20speech)

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical about it.

Comment: @ColinFine It isn't correct grammar. It's commonly used this way, but it's slang.

Comment: I am not interested in the purely social judgment implied by the word "correct". I say that there is nothing ungrammatical about it.

Comment: You say grammatical, I say grammahtical. http://xkcd.com/1483/